# Will forcing `group by` to sort DESC speed up code up, or slow it down?

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

In MySQL `group by` does an implicit `order by ASC`.
This is great if you wanted to add an `ORDER BY ASC` because then the results are already ordered.

But if you want to `ORDER BY .. DESC` MySQL has to order the resultset exactly the other way round.

**Will this trick speed up the select, slow it down, or do nothing at all**

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM atable 
GROUP BY -mydate   -- group by trick to force a `group by ... desc`
ORDER BY mydate DESC
```

I know I can just time the code, but I'm looking to gain some deeper insight into the issues at hand.
All the relevant indexes are in place naturally, because it would be silly to optimize without indexes.

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: Well, actually as far as I know, there is surely a performance difference and it is on slower side, however I feel that this slowness is negligible. I do not have any concrete articles on this now tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my tests, adding any sort a modifier to group by like `-` to change the sort order slows things down.

However you are allowed to specify:

```
SELECT id, name, sum(amount) FROM customers GROUP BY id DESC
```

And MySQL will happily order the results in DESC order without needing an extra `order by` clause.  This will not incur the extra runtime that adding the `-` does.

Comment: Since you have already set up a table and tests, can you test the performance differences between `GROUP BY id`, `GROUP BY id DESC` and `GROUP BY id ORDER BY NULL` ?

Comment: @ypercube, my main computer is borken, so I don't have the dataset for testing available. Will get back as soon as that's fixed.

Comment: I was looking for the same and figured I would just test it as have a bit of data to test with. Came out pretty much 100% as Johan said, https://gist.github.com/3681119

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken: `GROUP BY` doesn't sort data. It's the default MySQL behaviour that does, as MySQL adds the same `ORDER BY` as the `GROUP BY` you've set, as you've mentioned in your first sentence.

So, if you disable the sort, by using `ORDER BY NULL`, there's no sorting at all. The `GROUP BY` will only group rows together, using indexes if possible. Hence the «trick» is wrong, as you'll remove the ability to use an index on `mydate`. `GROUP BY` performs great as long as the index is good for it.

So:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM atable 
GROUP BY mydate
ORDER BY NULL
```

should be really fast if you have an index on (`mydate`), and

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM atable 
GROUP BY mydate
ORDER BY mydate DESC
```

should be as fast (depending on the table structure, MyISAM is a little bit slower in reverse order).

If you have a WHERE clause, check that you've added the columns in the index, for example:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM atable 
WHERE fied1 = 5
GROUP BY mydate
ORDER BY mydate DESC
```

will need an index on (`field1`,`mydate`).

Answer (score 0):

**Slow It Down**

What's happening here is that you are asking MySQL to sort the records based on a (probably) non-indexed column `mydate`.

Any sort takes time, but sorts on indexed columns are blazing fast compared to non-indexed ones.

Here's some additional reading: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: Naturally all indexes are in place, because it is silly to optimize without having proper indexes.

Comment: thanks for the link, but it did not really address the issue.